# Is map extension available for developers

Tags: ios, ios10

Here is a piece of news [How to Enable and Use Apple Maps Extensions in iOS 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/274476/how-to-enable-and-use-apple-maps-extensions-in-ios-10/)

It indicates that Apple has opened map extension for 3rd party apps. But I searched everywhere in Apple's document on this extension and ended up finding nothing.

Is it only open for Apps from well-known companies ?

Comment: It won't be like that at all. Do you have the XCode 8. Maybe thats the issue.

Comment: http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/30/new-third-party-ios-10-app-extensions-designed-to-extend-siri-maps-in-tandem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's a part of SiriKit. You can find the documentation here
[SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html)
and here [IntentsUI](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intentsui) and here [Intents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents).

So to answer your questions: yes, it's open for developers and not just well-known companies.